# how to create manual contrasts with emmeans? - R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Suppose I have these data

```
library(MASS)
m<-lmer(Y~N*V + (1|B),data=oats)
```

How can I create a manual contrast in `emmeans`? For example

```
Victoria_0.2cwt    1
Victoria_0.4cwt   -1
Marvellous_0.2cwt -1
Marvellous_0.4cwt  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emm = emmeans(m, ~ V * N)
emm
contrast(emm, list(con = c(0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0)))
```

However, this is actually a linear function, not a contrast, because the coefficients do not sum to zero.

Note: I may have mis-remembered the factor levels, and if so, the coefficients may need to be rearranged. They should correspond to the combinations you see in the results if the 2nd line

Comment: thanks, you are right. I forgot to add the last row (I edited the question), but I assume the answer is `contrast(emm, list(con = c(0,0,0,0,-1,1,0,1,-1,0,0,0)))`, right?

Comment: btw, is this contrast one-sided or two-sided?

Comment: There’s no such thing as a one- or two-sides contrast. It’s all in how you construct a test or CI for it. See `?summary.emmGrid`